# Are MRFs with edges to all observed data possible?

Tags: machine-learning, graphical-model

I have been discussing the following issue with a colleague of mine and I can't seem to wrap my head around it. I have a computer vision background, so I'm mostly familiar with 2D MRFs/CRFs for image restoration and segmentation.

What is clear to me is that MRFs typically have a simple 2D grid structure for p(x) and each underlying variable x_i has an edge to the corresponding pixel y_i in the graph for the posterior p(y|x). In CRFs you have an edge to each pixel y in the image. I can fully understand that CRFs are trained in a discriminative way and thus they are tractable and that it wouldn't be possible to really learn a generative model based on such a CRF graph. However in all the literature it seems that by definition the MRF model cannot have edges from a x_i to all pixels y, as it then would no longer be a MRF. For example the [following](http://www.sanjivk.com/DRF_bookchapter_ICVSS.pdf) states:

> If the conditional independence assumption is not used, the posterior will usually not be a MRF making the inference difficult.

Now that it would not be tractable to actually learn such a model I can understand, but why would it no longer be an MRF and also what would it be then? Because I don't see why it would by definition become a CRF, as we do not NEED to condition it on the data.

I really hope someone can tell me what I am missing here, or where my mistake is!

Comment: Can you define "MRF" & "CRF"?

Comment: @gung Markov random field and Conditional random field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restricted Boltzmann Machines are Markov random fields that usually have complete connectivity between the hidden and visible variables.  If we drop the "restricted" part and look at [Boltzmann Machines](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Boltzmann_machine) more generally, there can also be complete connectivity among the visible variables (pixels).

So yes, they're possible.

I haven't read the whole paper you linked to, but here is my assessment of what they mean.

- If $p(x)$ is an MRF, and all the elements of $y$ are conditionally independent of one another given $x$, then $p(x, y)$ is also an MRF.
- If the $y$ variables are *not* conditionally independent of one another, then this will not *necessarily* be true (although it still could be).  For instance, if there were directed connections among the $y$ variables, then you wouldn't have an MRF anymore.

However, the case you seem to be thinking about, where there are undirected connections between the variables (like the Boltzmann Machines I linked to) are still considered MRFs because all their pieces are MRFs.

Comment: Aaah, I think after reading your interpretation of the sentence, I just misunderstood it. The thing is that my colleague argued that once additional edges are added from y variables to the x variables (as you typically have in CRFs), you would no longer have a MRF. He pointed me to this document for an explanation, but I wasn't really satisfied as his statement contradicted what I believed to know about MRFs. Thank you a lot for this answer!

Comment: If you add *directed* edges (like in CRFs), then it's not an MRF anymore, but *undirected* edges (like in Boltzmann Machines) are totally fine.